What’s the best way to differentiate user panel access?
TLDR: Filament::getCurrentPanel->getId() always returns the default panel id, even if filament is accessed via an alternative panel
I have a default AdminPanelProvider.php and an AppPanelProvider.php, they have distinct URLs and settings. I want to make App only accessible by anonymous users, so I am updating the canAccessPanel method to differentiate users.
The problem is the 'app' panel never seems to load programmatically! I tried dumping the value of Filament::getCurrentPanel->getId(), which returns 'admin' every time.
My App panel has a different URL, theme and content, so I know visually when I'm looking at that panel vs the default panel.
Is Filament::getCurrentPanel->getId() not working? Is there a better way to differentiate Panels from one another? I know I could always look at the URL of the request, but first I'd like to try what appears to be the intended way to differentiate between Panels.
